# Observer canvas background src dinamically generated

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-canvas

when first-time load canvas, `background.src` is empty.
In dialog (dialog is in the second component) I upload IMG but after the success, `background.src` is still empty, I need to refresh app to get `background.src = this.src`;.

How to set observable to change background.src after upload to call again `this.src = this.srcService.getImgURL(this.id) // returned string 'https://something.com/image/1234'`, because canvas is already loaded?

Or maybe something else instead of observable?

I tried to set timeout with 1 second on background src and this is working, but setTimeout is not an option to use in our app.

Can not use `background.onload = () => {...}` because I need src before this.

Thnx

**First component**

```
export class FirstComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('canvas', { static: true }) canvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.src = this.srcService.getImgURL(this.id) // returned string 'https://something.com/image/1234'
  const background = new Image();
  background.src = this.src;
}
}
```

**Second component**
The second component is a dialog where I choose and upload the image

```
 export class SecondComponent implements {
       constructor( @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: IInterface,
                    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SettingsComponent>) 
    ( ... )
      close() {
         this.dialogRef.close(null);
       }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but `background.src` is asynchronous and you cannot get around that fact.  So you would likely need a `fromEvent(background, "load")` observable to wait until the source is loaded before proceeding to the `SecondComponent`.  This is akin to `background.addEventListener("load", () => {})` or `background.onload = () => {}`

Comment: hi, I will try that idea... thnx

Answer (score 0):

After the image loads, you should set the background to the canvas as well using the 2d context:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.src = this.srcService.getImgURL(this.id);
  const background = new Image();
  background.src = this.src;
  background.onload = () => {
    const ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Octavian Mărculescu thnx for replay. I already use onLoad, but problem is, canvas is loaded bellow dialog (where I upload img) and after uploaded new img, background.src is not changed.... I try also .clearRect() but same situatuion

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that the background does not update after you select another image in your dialog, right? Because this piece of code is inside `ngAfterViewInit` and gets called just once.

Comment: Yes, that is problem

Comment: How do you get the image URL out of the dialog? What is your approach? Can you please include the implementation of the `SrcService` in the question content?